# Как привязать к js json? Как брать из него данные?

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
    "room": {

        "flamingo": 2

    }
}
```

JS:

```js
let p = document.getElementById("p");
p.textContent = "В комнате" + quantityflamigos + "фламинго.";
```

Как "вытащить" кол-во фламинго из json?

Comment: а где json находится?

Comment: json на этой же машине в той же папке

Comment: Тогда, если json файл неизменный, и используется сборщик (например webpack), то ему просто можно сделать из js  `import`. A если файл меняется динамически, то можно делать из js `fetch ... json()` -- https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: а если его иногда меняют?

Comment: Если часто меняют, и хочется без обновления страницы это заметить, тогда можно `fetch` в `setInterval`, например (интервал несколько секунд/минут)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй сделать так

```
let p = room.flamingo
console.log(p)
```

Comment: А привязать с помощью html?

Comment: это будет выглядеть примерно так `${p}` внутрь нужного тебе тега

Comment: но все это нужно делать с помощью шаблона в js просто так не вставить насколько я знаю